# How do you 'foreach' over a list of types in Scala, using the iterated value as a type parameter?

Tags: scala, foreach, types, implicit

I need to construct a large HashMap, however I would not like to enter each value into the map manually, here is an example.

```
val codecs = HashMap(
    "Foo" -> deriveEncoder[Foo],
    "Bar" -> deriveEncoder[Bar],
    "Qux" -> deriveEncoder[Qux],
  )
```

`deriveEncoder` is a function which takes a single type parameter. Ideally I would like something as follows:

```
val concreteClasses = List(Foo, Bar, Qux)
concreteClasses.foreach(T => codecs.put(T.name, deriveEncoder[T]))
```

This is not possible, but what would be a reasonable alternative to this?

The reasoning is also that it would allow the list of types to be passed in during object construction, decoupling the actual types with the implementation of the containing class itself.

Thank you

Comment: What's the definition of `deriveEncoder`?

Comment: @Dima It is in the Circe library.
final def deriveEncoder[A](implicit encode: Lazy[DerivedAsObjectEncoder[A]]): Encoder.AsObject[A] = encode.value

Comment: Any reason you want to have the map of codecs?

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to construct a `HashMap` dynamically at runtime where keys are types, however types are a compile-time construct. `TypeTag` is a way of transferring compile-time type information to the runtime. Perhaps something like this is possible

```
package example

import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case class Foo(i: Int)
case class Bar(i: Int)
case class Qux(i: Int)

trait Encoder[T] {
  def encode(v: T): String
}

object Encoder {
  def apply[T](implicit ev: Encoder[T]) = ev
  implicit val fooEncoder: Encoder[Foo] = v => v.toString
  implicit val barEncoder: Encoder[Bar] = v => v.toString
  implicit val quxEncoder: Encoder[Qux] = v => v.toString
}

object forEachOnTypes extends App {
  val concreteClasses = List(typeTag[Foo], typeTag[Bar], typeTag[Qux])

  def encodersFor(tps: List[TypeTag[_]]) = {
    val toolbox = universe.runtimeMirror(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader).mkToolBox()
    tps.map { tp =>
      tp.tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString -> toolbox.eval(toolbox.parse(s"""example.Encoder[${tp.tpe}]""")).asInstanceOf[Encoder[_]]
    }.to(HashMap)
  }

  val encoders = encodersFor(concreteClasses)
  encoders("Foo")
}
```

however I do not know if it reasonable since we would have to make use of `asInstanceOf`

```
encoders("Foo").asInstanceOf[Encoder[Foo]].encode(Foo(42))
```